# How to store generic Actions with different parameters in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary

I want to store delegates(Action) with one generic parameter in a `Dictionary` and I would like to avoid any Code Smell
regarding to down/up-casting if that is possible at all.

Basically I am implementing some kind of a Request/Response Callback manager where the user requests something from a 
REST API and provides me a callback with the correct Response object. In a nutshell the method the user calls looks like that:

`void GetUser(int id, Action<GetUserResponse> callback);`

I then, sent out the request and save the callback into my "Callback Manager". When the response from the server
comes in (mostly json) I parse it into a `GetUserResponse` object and fire the callback. However there are many different
Requests which have different response objects and the Callback Manager has to prioritize them (and also some other stuff)
Instead of having a Dictionary for every single request which stores the callbacks of that request, I would like to 
have a single Dictionary which stores all of the callbacks (and a unique id).

Basically something like this: (which obviously does not work like that)

`Dictionary<GUID,Action<T>> AllCallbacks;`

Is that possible without having to cast anything on the "user side"?

Comment: Does the response objects have anything in common? can you create an interface that is common to all of them?

Comment: unfortunately no. There are more or less only holding data which differs depending on the request

Comment: Can you give an example of two different request Action<T> objects that you need to store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at    [Dictionary of Action<T> Delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247859/dictionary-of-actiont-delegates).
Should give you some guidance of options available to you. I don't think there is a simple and elegant solution out of the box.
You could use    `Dictionary<GUID,Action<dynamic>> AllCallbacks;` but then you would need to type check and cast accordingly.

Comment: thank you for the link, the only difference is that I can have more then one delegate for one type. That would me solution a bit more complex